# display dates from an array in json in descending order in php

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file, where there are dates, but I want to sort them in descending order when they go through a foreach.

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": "50",
            "name": "Charlotte Johnson",
            "date": "2021-02-08 10:15:38"
        },
        {
            "id": "51",
            "name": "Emma Jones",
            "date": "2021-02-09 18:30:38"
        },
        {
            "id": "52",
            "name": "Benjamin Miller",
            "date": "2021-02-10 23:47:38"
        }
    ]
}
```

I loop through the data from the JSON file.
I use usort but the dates are still not showing descending.

```
<?php
    $datajson = json_decode(file_get_contents("results.json"));

    usort($datajson->posts, function($a, $b) {
       return strtotime($a->date) - strtotime($b->date);
    });

    foreach($datajson->posts as $row)
        {
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row->date));
            echo " Date: ". $date ."<br />";
        }
?>
```

the dates that the PHP shows me

```
Date: 2021-02-08 10:15:38
Date: 2021-02-09 18:30:38
Date: 2021-02-10 24:47:38
```

but I want to sort them in descending order and display them like this

```
Date: 2021-02-10 24:47:38
Date: 2021-02-09 18:30:38
Date: 2021-02-08 10:15:38
```

Can you help me with this query?

Comment: For descending, just reverse the parameters inside the callback `$b - $a`.

Comment: Also, not a sort issue, but this doesn't seem to be needed `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row->date));`

Comment: Thanks to both of you for indicate what the problem was. I already removed the line from the `$ date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse the function parameters.

```
usort($datajson->posts, function($a, $b) {
         return strtotime($b->date) - strtotime($a->date) ;
     });
```

Here is result output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already modified and it worked.